# grunt copy folder with absolute path in windows

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I created a grunt copy task in with the below settings

```
{expand: true, src: ['E:\\Temp\\Copy1\\*'], dest: 'E:\\Temp\\Copy2\\', filter: 'isFile'},
```

I get the following error. how to I copy from absolute path?

> Warning: Unable to create directory "E:\Temp\Copy2\E:" (Error code:
>   ENOENT). Used --force, continuing.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the `cwd` option, as the matches for the `src` glob are appended to the `dest` path.

If you want to copy the contents of `E:\\Temp\\Copy1\\` to `E:\\Temp\\Copy2\\`, you can do it like this:

```
{
  expand: true,
  cwd: 'E:\\Temp\\Copy1\\',
  src: ['*'],
  dest: 'E:\\Temp\\Copy2\\',
  filter: 'isFile'
}
```

The Grunt documentation explains [how the `cwd` and `src` options can be used](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) to work with files:

> - `cwd` All `src` matches are relative to (but don't include) this path.
> - `src` Pattern(s) to match, relative to the `cwd`.
> - `dest` Destination path prefix.